# Google Analytics - how to tell if users connects via wifi or cell?

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way to tell in Google Analytics if a user's session was via wifi or cellular?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.

> Google Analytics will not explicitly tell you whether or not a device
>   is on wifi. If your site has relatively low levels of traffic, a crude
>   way to estimate the number of mobile visits via wifi and 3G would be
>   to use the domain variable that is passed by the visitors ISP.
>
> If a device is on 3G, it's domain will show up as "mycingular.net"
>   "myvzw.com" and other domains that mobile cell companies provide for
>   their 3G (and 2G, 4G, LTE, etc) networks. If the device is on wifi,
>   the domain will show up as "rr.com" "comcast.net" "sbcglobal.net" or
>   whatever the domain is of the wireless network they are connected to.
>   Depending upon your level of traffic, there may be too many domains to
>   sort through to find out the exact number of visits on wifi or 3G.
>   Also, some domains may not be clear cut wifi or 3G (example: AT&T is a
>   cellular and internet provider).
>
> To see how many domains you would need to sort through, enable the
>   "Mobile" advanced segment, navigate to Audience-->Mobile-->Overview,
>   and set the secondary dimension as domain. The number of rows is equal
>   to the number of unique domains.

[Reference](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/analytics/y_-_ocqodw8)

Answer (score 2):

In the new Google analytics update, you have the possibility to access to the audience network providers, and from that concluding if it's from Wifi or 2G/3G/4G.

1. Open Google Analytics Console.
2. Go to Audience > Technology > Network.
3. Scroll to the bottom, you can see then a table with Service providers/ Audience(New users, Users, Session).

Answer (score 0):

This service provider dimension in GA is already deprecated. https://www.leadfeeder.com/blog/dear-google-why-oh-why-did-you-remove-service-provider-and-network-domain-from-analytics/

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.